# Where are logs created by drush_log() stored?

Tags: drush, debugging

I have installed Devel module to use xhprof. In devel settings, I have enabled xhprof, but when I load a page, can't see a link to xhprof. I read the source and found this:

`drush_log('xhprof link: ' . devel_xhprof_link($devel_run_id, 'url'), 'notice');`

Where is this log stored and how can I see it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not. It's printed.

However, notices are by default not visible unless you increase the verbosity of drush using the -v option.

To display internal messages you'll need to enable debug option -d. This will display even more information.

Alternatively, you can change the [message type parameter](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/includes!drush.inc/function/drush_log/6.x) from 'notice' to 'ok' to print out to the console.

```
drush_log('xhprof link: ' . devel_xhprof_link($devel_run_id, 'url'), 'ok');
```

Comment: Does this mean that I should use terminal to check reports instead of web browser?If yes which command should I use? When I load a page in browser nothing is printed.

Comment: The drush log is *only* when you execute a command with drush, to see the xhprof report of that command. The link for the page you're viewing is displayed right on the page if permissions/path to xdebug is correctly set up, as you've found out by now.

Comment: You can pass status 'OK' to bypass the need for -v. Documentation: http://api.drush.ws/api/drush/includes%21drush.inc/function/drush_log/6.x